# Cypher Query in Qlikview

Tags: neo4j, qlikview

I have connected Neo4j with Qlikview and I'm firing the cypher query. Now I have two graphs with the same labels so when I make a report in Qlikview I'm finding the aggregate count value of a particular label retrieved from both the graphs. So in order to get the data from only one graph can I fire the query with graph name say 'emp' prefixed with the label as below.
SQL MATCH a=(emp.cname)-[:has]->(emp.clusters)   RETURN cname.name as cName, clusters.name as ClustName; where emp is the name of the graph from which I want to get the data and cname and clusters are the labels.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you managed to make the connection between QV and Neo4j work? Using Cypher from QV sounds fantastic :)

Comment: You can connect to Neo4j from QlikView via JDBC Connector and then code Cypher queries in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is technically only *one* graph. It seems that you have create two sub-graphs in that space and need a way of disguising them. That is typically done by creating an *anchor* node that at least one of the sub-graph nodes is related to or to add a unique label to each set of nodes to distinguish them. If that is not an option then you could run a preliminary query to determine the two start nodes (distinguished by some property/label or that are not connected in any way) and using one or the other for the query of interest.